# SQL - Find duplicate lines in two tables

Tags: mysql, sql, join, duplicates

this seems like a very easy question and in fact I know how to help myself but I hope to find a quicker approach to this problem.

I have two tables with the same structure in an sql-dbms, whereas some lines of data occur in both tables. My way of finding these duplicates is making an inner-join with all columns in the "on-statement", like:

```
create table target as
  select 
   a.column_1
   a.column_2
   a.column_3
   ...
   a.column_20
from table source_1 as a
inner join source_2 as b
 on a.column_1 = b.column_1 and 
    a.column_2 = b.column_2 and
    ...
    a.column_20 = b.column_20
;
```

With a large amount of columns in the tables, this produces a long piece of code. Is there some kind of syntax or method to make this shorter?
Thanks for your help,
kind regards.

Comment: In general, having the same values in the primary keys, implies same values in the other columns too. What is your primary key look like ?

Comment: Thank you for your hint. This is  a point I forgot to mention. Unfortunately there is no such thing like a single primary key in these tables. Most likely the lines will be unique by a selection of six or seven of the columns. But since I am not totally sure, I prefer to join the tables based on all columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your tables are of same structure then try using the following query,

```
select * from source_1
INTERSECT
select * from source_2
```

it will give you the common rows from both the tables

Comment: In the actual case both approaches (the join on all columns and the intersect) result in a different number of lines. Anyhow, I think that this is the way to do it. Thanks a lot.